# please help - count string in java

Tags: java

Hi i am beginner of programming/Java, i am trying to do a simple program to count "char ch" within a String, so i wrote this below, and i can not compile, could anyone please let me know why?:

```
public class StringProblems {

     public int count(String s,char ch) {

        int count;
        int l =s.length();
        char result =charAt(s);

        for(int n=0; n<=l; n++){

            if(result=='c') {
                if(result == 'h') {
                    count ++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `count`. Give it an initial value of `0`.

Comment: @RohitJain let's see how many people will post an answer pointing this waiting to earn free rep.

Comment: There are more than 1 things going wrong here. Care to share your errors

Comment: thx i just did, but this one is wrong - char result =charAt(s); per my compiler

Comment: `but this one is wrong - char result =charAt(s); per my compiler` it definitely is and do you know why?

Comment: because s is a String, not an int

Comment: This is clearly a "bug count" test, or "fix the bugs" question, for the guy's homework. Unless, unwittingly, he has written **almost every bug possible** in such a simple piece of code...

Comment: See my answer where I enumerate & count them.. **I'm not going to try & fix them.**

Comment: Honestly I would have preferred the OP putting in some more efforts from his end as almost all the errors are compile time errors and his IDE would have told him exactly where and what was going wrong

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly a "bug count" test, or "fix the bugs" question for homework -- unless, unwittingly, you have written almost every bug possible in such a simple piece of code...

Counting them:

1. Uninitialized result variable.
2. String method-call error.
3. String indexing placed *outside* of loop.
4. Loop bounds error.
5. Parameter/requirement taken as a **literal**.
6. Adjacency logic error.
7. Return before loop end.

Personally, I would have fitted one more in.. on the single line of code that doesn't have an error :)  And perhaps also one for the method/ or class declaration.

Comment: Good point, but the **leaving out of whitespace** and the too large number of bugs is really too much for a serious test. _I would not like to work with someone who invented such a test._

Comment: 7 bugs, in a function that only needs 5 lines of code, is pretty good going :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not C. C usually passes objects around and has operations performed on them. In Java and most object oriented languages, you usually ask an object to **do something for you**.
This is done with the following syntax:

```
object.doThis(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Do this:

```
public class StringProblems {

    public int count(String s,char ch) {

        int count = 0; //initialize the variable
        int l =s.length();
        //char result =charAt(s); //don't need this. It should be **in** the loop

        for(int n=0; n < l; n++){ //changed to <. <= will give you an index out of range 
                                  //runtime error
            char result = String.charAt(n); //moved the call to here
            if(result=='c') {
                if(result == 'h') {
                    count ++;
                }
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Also, this will never work because the char can only hold one value. It will never be both c and h at the same time.

A loop more like this can detect the "ch" combo.

```
    public int count(String s,char ch) {

        int count = 0;
        int l =s.length();
        //char result =charAt(s); //don't need this. It should be **in** the loop

        for(int n=0; n < l - 1; n++){
            char first = String.charAt(n); //moved the call to here

            if(first=='c') {
                char second = String.charAt(n+1); //check the character right after 'c'
                if(second == 'h') {
                    count ++;
                }
            }

        }
        return count;
    }
```

This works because it only checks to the second to last character in the string. If the last character in the string is a c, there cannot be an h after it. If one of the characters you check is a c, you check for an h right after. You can optimize this by screwing with the for variable and incrementing it by 1 when you find a ch (because the next iteration cannot find a ch), but messing with the for counter var is a bad idea.

Now that I look at your function parameters though (char ch), I suppose you're looking for the character in the string s and not for "ch" exactly as in "chihuaha".

If so, then your function can find any character inside of a string by the following:

```
    //counts the number of times ch appears in s
    public int count(String s,char ch) {

        int l =s.length();

        for(int n=0; n < l; n++){
            char result = String.charAt(n); //call inside the loop

            if(first==ch) {
                count ++;
            }

        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me one thing. How can result be equal to `c` and then equal to `h` ? And where is `count` initialized

Comment: @Prateek, it won't. I've given a loop that can check for this though.

Answer (score -1):

int count is a local variable thus it has to be initialized before use. Set it to zero and you should be all set.